# zsh: command not found: {compinstall,compinit,compdef}

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

The `zshcompsys` `man`-page says:

> INITIALIZATION
>
> If the system was installed completely, it should be enough to call the shell function `compinit` from your initialization file;  see 
>   the  next  section.   However,  the  function
>          `compinstall` can be run by a user to configure various aspects of the completion system.

`zsh` can't find the commands though:

```
genesis% compinit
zsh: command not found: compinit
genesis% compinstall
zsh: command not found: compinstall
genesis% echo $PATH
/home/ravi/bin:/home/ravi/.gem/ruby/2.4.0/bin:/home/ravi/bin:/home/ravi/.gem/ruby/2.4.0/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/default/bin:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl:/usr/local/heroku/bin:/home/ravi/.cabal/bin:/home/ravi/.local/share/fzf/bin:/usr/local/heroku/bin:/home/ravi/.cabal/bin
genesis%
```

I'm lead to ask this question because when starting `zsh` I get:

```
tmuxinator.zsh:20: command not found: compdef
```

How do I get `zsh` to find these completion commands?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

This is the same issue I got on my mac. I am using zsh shell.

[image: Zsh Compdef error]

Compdef is basically a function used by zsh for load the auto-completions. The completion system needs to be activated. If you’re using something like **oh-my-zsh** then this is already taken care of, otherwise you’ll need to add the following to your ~/.zshrc

```
autoload -Uz compinit
compinit
```

Completion functions can be registered manually by using the compdef function directly like this compdef  . But compinit need to be autoloaded in context before using compdef.

Comment: I tried this but got "compinit:503: no such file or directory: /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_brew
compinit:503: no such file or directory: /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_brew_cask" Guessing that is because I don't use homebrew so this answer may be a problem for people like me.

Comment: This is what I needed on MacOS 12.6. Thanks!

Comment: If you're using oh-my-zsh and still getting this, make sure to put your `compdef` _after_ the `source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh` line in `~/.zshrc`.

Comment: what are the options U and z for?

Answer (score 16):

#### Answer to the question as asked

Access these commands by running:

```
$ autoload -Uz compinstall && compinstall
```

It will load a guided wizard, I quit as soon as I had the option to `Save and exit`.

Then reload the shell:

```
$ exec zsh
```

#### More general answer

It appears that the new user configuration was not run.

Run it by:

```
$ autoload -Uz zsh-newuser-install && zsh-newuser-install -f
```

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue.

For me I did the following:

- Closed the current terminal
- Ran the command `brew doctor` to fix any brew package concern
- And finally ran the command `rm -f ~/.zcompdump; compinit`