# Tab completion on mosh (ssh) alias?

Tags: bash, autocomplete, mosh

I've just started using [mosh](https://mosh.org/) and I'm left thinking to myself "why didn't I start using this like two years ago?"

I'm even more impressed by the fact that it reads my `~/.ssh/config` and respects the aliases in it. The only thing I'd like now is for tab completion on the aliases, like ssh does. Is there a way?

Comment: Do you mean completion of aliases on the command line of `ssh` or `mosh`, i.e. when you type `mosh myni<TAB>` and it completes to `mosh mynickname`? That's done by your shell, probably bash, zsh or fish. What shell are you using?

Comment: Why didn't you use it *6 years ago*? https://gist.github.com/aliang/1024466

Comment: Because I was probably running a pirate copy of Windows 7 at the time (shudder). :0)

Comment: @Gilles I'm using bash. I'm gonna try either an alias or setting something in my hosts file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added some `.bash_aliases` to log into my various systems:

```
alias mj='mosh j3710'
alias m3='mosh 3770k'
etc.
etc.
```

I tried adding them to `/etc/hosts` but it didn't work. I'm sure there's probably a neater way of doing it but if nothing is suggested within the next couple of days I'll mark this as answered.

Answer (score 2):

`zsh` has great autocomplete functionality.  Install zsh and make sure completion is setup (instructions [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/339954/)).  The parts related to ssh you want in your `.zshrc`:

```
zstyle ':completion:*:ssh:*' hosts
compdef mosh=ssh
```

The first line will allow you to use allow tab completion of host names in response to `ssh`.  The second line extend the same hostname extensions to mosh as well